# Разбивка текста на предложения

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

пришла весна в лесу поют птицы дятлы звонко стучат по стволу вот прыгнул под куст заяц в траве шуршат ежи ёжики ищут пищу в тени цветёт душистый ландыш

Answer (score 1):

Пришла весна. В лесу поют птицы. Дятлы звонко стучат по стволу. Вот прыгнул под куст заяц. В траве шуршат ежи. Ёжики ищут пищу. В тени цветёт душистый ландыш.

Answer (score 1):

Да, с точками - проще всего. А можно так:

"Пришла весна: в лесу поют птицы, дятлы звонко стучат по стволу... Вот прыгнул под куст заяц. В траве шуршат ежи - ёжики ищут пищу. В тени цветёт душистый ландыш."

Хотя я бы заменил "ёжики" на "они".